# python, wordle, removing words in list that do not have the matching properties

Tags: python, wordle-game

first post and new to python
working on a wordle game where the user inputs a word and the computer tries to figure out the word. I'm trying (for a start) to just mark the green and grey/black letters. I want to remove words from the new_word_list that don't have the green (g) index in the word. I have tangled myself in a mess and need some help with solving this dilemma, thank you in advance...

```
from words_utf import word_list
import random
import os


random_word = random.choice(word_list)
word_length = len(random_word)


display = []
for _ in range(word_length):
    display += "_"



end_game = False
possible_match = []
final_word = ""
new_word_list=[]

chosen_word = input("Choose a word:\n").lower()
if chosen_word not in word_list:
    print("Input a word from the words_utf.txt file")
else:
    
    while not end_game:
        if final_word.join(display) == chosen_word:
            print("Computer wins!")
            end_game = True
        else:
            os.system('cls')
            print(f"You chose: {chosen_word}")
            print(display)
            print("Computer guesses:")
            random_word = print(random.choice(word_list))
            print(
                "G for Green (correct letter on correct position)\nY for Yellow (correct letter on incorrect position)\nB for Black (incorrect letter)")
            response = input("Enter your response\n").lower()
            #if len(response) < 5 or len(response) > 5:
            #    print("Try again.")
            if len(response) == len(chosen_word) and set(response) <= {"g", "y", "b"}:
                for i, char in enumerate(chosen_word):
                            if response[i] == "g":
                                chosen_word[i] == random_word[i]
                                display[i] = char
                                new_word_list.remove(word_list[i] == random_word[i])
                                
                            #elif response[i] == "y":
                            
            else:
                print(f"Invalid answer {response}")
                    
        #print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt look clearly at your code, i just find where you want to remove the word from `new_word_list`.

> `new_word_list.remove(word_list[i] == random_word[i])`

in this line of code, `word_list[i] == random_word[i]` is an operation which return boolean to you.

if `word_list[i]` is equal to `random_word[i]`, you will get a `True` as return. the line above will be `new_word_list.remove(True)`, which will remove nothing because `True` is not in the list.

u can try to change it first.